# I'm getting "Key error" in code calc(X, y, model, stkfold)

Tags: python

I'm getting this error:

```
KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
<timed exec> in <module>

<ipython-input-231-aa032fdd2ccd> in calc(X, y, model, cv)

---> 19         X_train, X_valid, y_train, y_valid = X.iloc[tdx], X.iloc[vdx], y[tdx], y[vdx]
```

This is the code:

```
%%time
probs = calc(X, y, model, stkfold)
```

[Here is the complete code:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lgaso.png)

Comment: How are we supposed to answer without knowing what `calc()` does?

Comment: Please post code, data, and results as text, not screenshots ([how to format code in posts](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting)). [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors) http://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode

Comment: Since there are 4 different indexes in that expression, it's hard to tell which one is getting the error. Split it up into 4 assignments so you can tell where the error is happening. Then you should be able to figure out how to fix it.

Comment: E.g. `X_train = X.iloc[tdx]` then `X_valid = X.iloc[vdx]` and so on.

Comment: `keyerror` usually occurs when you are trying to access a non-existent key in a dictionary.